# How to do calculation in forms in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form action="" method="post">
Color: <input type="text" name="Color"><br>
  ProductID: <input type="text" name="ProductID"><br>
  <!-- Receiver Nam: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br> -->
  Amount: <input type="text" name="Amount"><br>
  Price: <input type="text" name="Price"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button red">

</form>
```

To multiple Amount by Price

Comment: Welcome, Please read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. Its like there is a cliffhanger

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
Color: <input type="text" name="Color"><br>
  ProductID: <input type="text" name="ProductID"><br>
  <!-- Receiver Nam: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br> -->
  Amount: <input type="text" name="Amount"><br>
  Price: <input type="text" name="Price"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button red">

</form>  



<?php

/* get the posted data */
$productId = $_POST['ProductID'];
$lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
$amount = $_POST['Amount'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];

$totalPrice = ($amount*$price); /*multiply the amount by the price */

/* print the result */
echo "Hi ".$lastName;
echo "Total Price is: ".$totalPrice;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, Sorry im new but how do you do it in javascript?

Comment: JavaScript multiplication is just the same as php.